# Send byte array as a property by ActiveMQ

Tags: java, jms, arrays, activemq-classic

How can I send `byte array` as a message property(but not in body!) by `ActiveMQ`?

**I wanna compress(Deflate) some properties and decompress(Inflate) them on destination**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JMS spec states: Property values can be boolean, byte, short, int, long, float, double, and String.

So im pretty sure you cant use byte array however there is nothing stopping you encoding that byte array and sending it as a string.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jms/Message.html